How do I bound an equation to a range?
Suppose I have:
if a > 1:
   b = 1
elif a < 0
   b = 0
else:
   b = a

How would I write this as an equation in LaTeX?
Or would I want something like this:
b = min(max(a,1),0)


Why not just b = \min(\max(a,1),0)? Otherwise one would normally use a cases env

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Shouldn't the order of the min and max operations be reversed in b = min(max(a,1),0)? I.e., shouldn't you be computing b = max(min(a,1),0)?

b = \max(\min(a,1),0) is what I've been using, I don't know Latex very well, and was hoping for something more elegant. –

b = \max(\min(a,1),0) is in direct contradiction to b = \min(\max(a,1),0), which is what you wrote in the query. Please fix.

Here are two possibilities that employ a cases environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
b=
\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $a>1$},\\
  0 & \text{if $a<0$},\\
  a & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\qquad\qquad
b=
\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $a>1$},\\
  a & \text{if $0\le a\le 1$},\\
  0 & \text{if $a<0$.}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}


This is useful for my simple example, but suppose I had a really long set of terms instead of 'a'

@Brad - Sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, all my life my mind-reading skills have  been utterly worthless, and they will almost certainly remain worthless going forward. If you don't intend to use a but, rather, "a really long set of terms", then you need to provide a specific example of what you have in mind. For the odds that I will be able to come up with such an example (especially one that's relevant for you) are decidedly poor. Sorry.


\documentclass[preview, margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}% dcases environment
\usepackage{amssymb}% leqslant symbol

\begin{document}
\[
    b =
        \begin{dcases}
            1 & \text{if } a > 1, \\
            0 & \text{if } a < 0, \\
            a & \text{otherwise.}
        \end{dcases}
    \quad
    b =
        \begin{dcases}
            1 & a > 1, \\
            a & 0 \leq a \leq 1, \\
            0 & a < 0.
        \end{dcases}
    \quad
    b =
        \begin{dcases}
            1 & a > 1, \\
            a & 0 \leqslant a \leqslant 1, \\
            0 & a < 0.
        \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}


Please elaborate on why you'd use a dcases environment rather than a cases environment.

I sgrre with @Mico here there is nothing that would benefit from dcases here.

It's just a personal preference, as the mathtools package extends amsmath, and the dcases environment supports a wider variety of cases where it can be used.

The difference between the cases and dcases environments is twofold: the default use of display-style math mode instead of text-style math mode, and the wider line-spacing. The claim that "the dcases environment supports a wider variety of cases where it can be used" seems to be at variance with reality: Both environments can be used for the same variety of cases. Use dcases when it's called for (which isn't the case here). Pun intended.

Ahah, thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll leave the response as it is so that the comments make sense :)
